# IE 11 throws exceptions when debugging responsive Web app with Bootstrap in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-11

When I resize the browser window and I hit a responsive breaking point, this (dynamic) method throws an exception at line 3:

```
window.__BROWSERTOOLS_CONSOLE_SAFEFUNC = function (fn) {
                var returnFn = function () {
                    return fn(arguments);
                };
                return returnFn;
            }
```

> Unhandled exception at line 5, column 25 in eval code
>
> 0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Unspecified error.

I think what this does is manage listeners for media query evaluation changes, but the *arguments* contain a bunch of methods that I did not try to analyze further. I have to click away about two dozens of these errors before I can continue.

When the browser is not attached to the debugger, it works fine.
Is anybody else experiencing this, and can I turn it off?

Comment: I sometimes get javascript errors when trying to resize the window when using bootstrap. I never looked further as restarting the debug session seemed to fix it.

Comment: I'm getting it when using history.js (at least in IE11 -> IE9 compability mode), again, with console turned on.

Comment: To make things more depressing: I've tracked the problem to one of JS files. I figured that one of the keywords within it might be causing the problem. Then I removed everything from it - still error. Then I removed the inclusion of that empty file - no errors. ;_:

Comment: I know this is late but this is not related to Bootstrap. I have a similar issue with a Webapp in IE11 without Bootstrap

Comment: Future googler here, I opened a ticket with Microsoft Edge recently related to this issue.

In my case, exceptions occurred in any code that contained console.log after opening/closing f12 debugger tools when the code being executed was contained in a child iframe. Ticket link below has attachment with simple case outlined.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7942209/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was experiencing this too and it drove me nuts... Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Load you page; it works great. Try resizing, it works great.
2. Pull up developer tools, continue browsing your site, resize works good
3. Hide the developer tools.. resize.. CRAP, error

Something about the page (Bootstrap's CSS or JS) freaks out when you hide the debugger.  **Luckily the fix is easy, just push CTRL+R** to force a hard-reload of the page, which will clear the error

I guess the preventative step (so you don't have to hold down ESC to clear the alerts) would be to CTRL+R each time you hide the F12 tools

Comment: I was going to give a hope to IE11, I guess it still let me down.

Comment: And no hopes were given