# console.log/info/assert undefined on cordova Windows8.1 after a click on a select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console, windows-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I've got some issues with cordova/angularJS on Windows8.1.

I tried to search the whole of google before asking here, but it seems that I'm stuck.

The cordova App I made does work correctly on all other platforms (iOs, Android, Chrome ...even IE11 & Windows Phone).
But When I tried to run it on Windows8, all basic console functions stopped working. (console.log .info .assert etc. become undefined, but the object *console* still exists)

The problem seems to come from two select placed in my screen.
When I click on them to display their options, my console is instantly replaced by another object, that does not contain the basic console functions (log, assert, info, etc.)

I don't even know where to debug, the console modification seems to be made before any function I added.

```
<select
    class="selectPicker"
    value="{{ item[mfField.valueAttribute] }}"
    name="select"
    ng-model="mfField.selectedItemValue"
    ng-required="false"
    ng-readonly="false"
    ng-disabled="false"
    bo-attr
    bo-id="{{ mfId }}"
    ng-options="item[mfField.valueAttribute] as getContent(item) | translate for item in mfField.itemsList">
</select>
```

Note: the problem seems to come from the presence of the JavaScript console. I tried to install the appx on a surface, the problem disappeared. I installed the remote debugger, the appx crashed again.

Note 2: No, I can't get rid of all console.log/info/assert of my app, I need them for some bugs.

*Just in case It's a compatibility problem: 
I'm on Cordova 4.3.0, on a Windows8.1 image on VMWare Fusion, with Visual Studio 2013, and the last test was made on a Surface (Windows RT 8.1) but the same problem appeared on the VM and the simulator.
Also I used angular 1.3 and bootstrap 3.3.4*

**EDIT:** For the beauty of desperation, I added the most basic select I could find to my screen

```
<select> 
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
   <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> 
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

The problem still persists.

Comment: Check the source code for the `bo-attr` and `bo-id` directives. As well as the `getContent` function.

Comment: For the beauty of desperation, I added the most basic select I could find to my screen

`<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>`

The problem still persists...

Answer (score 0):

`console` is *not* a Cordova feature. It's a browser specific feature, and it's not reliable on Windows. There are numerous javascript libraries you can get that will standardize the `console` object across platforms.

Cordova has a number of logger alternatives to use than the `console` object, but since you're using a purely Javascript tool like AngularJS. You'll need a JavaScript fix for it.

You could use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which would fix the problem, but it's heavy just to fix a single issue.

I would just copy the console fix taken from the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/).

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeline', 'timelineEnd', 'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

**EDIT:**

After a second read of the question. I misunderstood that `console` is being replaced. You can ignore this answer, but I'll keep it here just incase it helps someone else.

Comment: That's the worst part, I've got Modernizr set in place, but I doesn't seem to work.
I had to add the winstore-jscompat.js script to make the windows8 project work, and I wonder if there's some incompatibility at work here...

EDIT : Ok, Cheers for the answer still

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is answered here ...

[IE 11 throws exceptions when debugging responsive Web app with Bootstrap in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884457/ie-11-throws-exceptions-when-debugging-responsive-web-app-with-bootstrap-in-visu)

The console was replaced by the function __BROWSERTOOLS_CONSOLE_SAFEFUNC, which seems to be a common error in JS with Visual studio...caused by the existence of said console in visual studio...

...the answer? *do not use the javascript console* ...

... I'm keeping the thread open, in case someone has a solution that does not forbid me a proper debug of my application...